# Error during calculating parametres (unsupported operand type)

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I'm trying to calculate linear regression for my small data science project.

I have class

```
import numpy as np

# I'm using the idea from https://devarea.com/linear-regression-with-numpy/#.XRfdcegzaUk
class LinearRegression:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.y = np.array(values)
        self.x = np.array([number for number in range(1, len(values)+1)])
        self.values_to_return = []

    def getlinear(self, x1):
        # Function that returns value
        def inner(x1):
            return self.m * x1 + self.b

        self.m = (len(self.x) * np.sum(self.x*self.y) - np.sum(self.x) * np.sum(self.y)) / (len(self.x)*np.sum(self.x*self.x) - np.sum(self.x) * np.sum(self.x))
        self.b = (np.sum(self.y) - self.m*np.sum(self.x)) / len(self.x)

        return inner
```

And I got error

> File "c:/Users/Paweł/Documents/projects vscode/WorldBankDataKeras/tests.py", line 35, in 
>       country1 = data.CountryInformations('Poland')
>     File "c:\Users\Paweł\Documents\projects vscode\WorldBankDataKeras\data.py", line 26, in **init**
>       linear.return_values_of_linear_regression())
>     File "c:\Users\Paweł\Documents\projects vscode\WorldBankDataKeras\linear_regr.py", line 22, in return_values_of_linear_regression
>       self.values_to_return.append(self.getlinear(x_param))
>     File "c:\Users\Paweł\Documents\projects vscode\WorldBankDataKeras\linear_regr.py", line 15, in getlinear
>       self.m = (np.array(len(self.x)) * np.sum(self.x*self.y) - np.sum(self.x) * np.sum(self.y)) / (np.array(len(self.x))*np.sum(self.x*self.x) - np.sum(self.x) * np.sum(self.x))
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'dict_values'

What do I do wrong?

EDIT:

When passing list(dictionary.values()) into the class I got

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:/Users/Paweł/Documents/projects vscode/WorldBankDataKeras/tests.py", line 41, in 
>       graph.plot_graph_renewable_electricity_status()
>     File "c:\Users\Paweł\Documents\projects vscode\WorldBankDataKeras\graph_plotting.py", line 115, in plot_graph_renewable_electricity_status
>       linestyle='-')
>     File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py", line 1810, in inner
>       return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 1612, in plot
>       self.add_line(line)
>     File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 1895, in add_line
>       self._update_line_limits(line)
>     File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 1917, in _update_line_limits
>       path = line.get_path()
>     File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 945, in get_path
>       self.recache()
>     File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 645, in recache
>       y = _to_unmasked_float_array(yconv).ravel()
>     File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook__init__.py", line 1365, in _to_unmasked_float_array
>       return np.asarray(x, float)
>     File "C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
>       return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>   TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'

EDIT 2:

```
class CountryInformations:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

        xls_parsing = xls_parse.XLSParsing(self.name)

        self.population = xls_parsing.import_country_population()
        self.co2_emissions = xls_parsing.import_country_co2_emissions()
        self.renewable_electricity_status = xls_parsing.import_country_renewable_electricity_status()

        # I want to have linear regression values in format [year] : value
        self.population_linear_regression = self.population.copy()
        self.co2_emissions_linear_regression = self.co2_emissions.copy()
        self.renewable_electricity_status_linear_regression = self.renewable_electricity_status.copy()

        linear = linear_regr.LinearRegression(list(self.population_linear_regression.values()))
        # Replacing values in dict by values from linear regression
        self.population_linear_regression = dict.fromkeys(self.population_linear_regression,
                                                          linear.return_values_of_linear_regression())

        linear = linear_regr.LinearRegression(list(self.co2_emissions_linear_regression.values()))
        # Replacing values in dict by values from linear regression
        self.co2_emissions_linear_regression = dict.fromkeys(self.co2_emissions_linear_regression,
                                                             linear.return_values_of_linear_regression())

        linear = linear_regr.LinearRegression(list(self.renewable_electricity_status_linear_regression.values()))
        # Replacing values in dict by values from linear regression
        self.renewable_electricity_status_linear_regression = dict.fromkeys(self.renewable_electricity_status_linear_regression, 
                                                                            linear.return_values_of_linear_regression())

    def __str__(self):
        print_string = 'Country: {} \n \
                        Population: {}M \n \
                        CO2 Emissions: {}KT \n \
                        Renewable Electricity Status: {}%'.format(self.name, \
                                                                  self.population, \
                                                                  self.co2_emissions, \
                                                                  self.renewable_electricity_status)
        return print_string
```

Comment: you are trying to multiply an integer by a dictionary , what is the type of values that are you passing to the class?

Comment: dictionary.values()

Comment: try passing ```list(dictionary.values())```

Comment: are you passing list(dictionary.values()) or dictionary.values() , you should pass the first one

Comment: Now I got TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'

Comment: I've edited post

Comment: the new error is in an another line bellow the code you are showing right now

Comment: I marked 'Edit"

Comment: i mean that your new error is in line 41 in your code , please provide the full code

Comment: https://github.com/fxdx/WorldBankDataProcessing

Comment: This is full project

Comment: can you include the code you are using to instantiate the `LinearRegression` object

Comment: I added it below EDIT 2

Comment: It may be helpful: I used this website https://devarea.com/linear-regression-with-numpy/#.XRjkEegzaUl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by deleting inner function. I don't know why it works by it does so

```
def getlinear(self, x1):

    self.m = (len(self.x) * np.sum(self.x*self.y) - np.sum(self.x) * np.sum(self.y)) / (len(self.x)*np.sum(self.x*self.x) - np.sum(self.x) * np.sum(self.x))
    self.b = (np.sum(self.y) - self.m*np.sum(self.x)) / len(self.x)

    return self.m * x1 + self.b
```

Thanks for helping everyone